# Will Virtual LANs slow down my network?

Tags: vpn

Will virtual LAN connections (peer to peer) like those made with https://www.freelan.org/ slow down my network?

Comment: Peer to peer home networking clients are off topic here

Comment: Where can I find what a stack exchange topic Is on the mobile app. It just said it’s about networking.

Comment: SuperUser.com.  Our site clearly explains that this is for professional networks

Comment: Apparently, you are confusing a Virtual Private Network (VPN) with a Virtual LAN (VLAN). Those are two completely separate concepts.

Comment: FReeLan.org said it was a virtual Lan. I need to make my computer think it’s on the same LAN as another pc even though they’re on separate networks.

Comment: The meaning of virtual lan has been constant for decades, describing the freelan network as a virtual lan redefines a term that has a very specific meaning to network engineers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLANs (Virtual LANs) are a way to divide a LAN (layer-2 broadcast domain) into multiple, virtual LANs that cannot directly communicate. You need a router (layer-3 device) in order to communicate from one VLAN to another VLAN, even if both exist on the same layer-2 switch.

Depending on your router, and how it is configured, you may see a slight slowdown in traffic between VLANs, but you have not provided enough information to even guess at that. You can also place ACL restrictions between the VLANs to control what traffic is, or is not, allowed between the VLANs.

Comment: He’s asking about a peer to peer client not a real VLAN